# How to require authentication on Django Rest Framework views?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to use a custom login url in specific view...

```
@login_required(login_url='/account/login/')
class home(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        template = get_template(template_name='myapp/template.html')
        return Response({}, template_name=template.template.name)
```

...but the traceback shows...

```
File "django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 22, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Is it possible to use custom login_required in class-based view?

Answer (score 24):

I think you are searching for Django Rest Framework APIView.

Here you can use permission classes: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

On your project's `seetings.py`:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

And on your code:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class home(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (TemplateHTMLRenderer,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        template = get_template(template_name='myapp/template.html')
        return Response({}, template_name=template.template.name)
```

Comment: this is probably the cleanest solution, as normal decorators are not usefull on the restframework endpoints.

Comment: I believe this is not the way to do this since permission classes return 403 and it's not possible to change that. in case of login failure or missing credentials it should return 401 not 403

Answer (score 13):

Decorators can only be used on functions, not classes.

However, for decorating class-based views the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class) suggest this:

> **Decorating the class**
>
> To decorate every instance of a class-based view, you need to decorate
>   the class definition itself. To do this you apply the decorator to the
>   `dispatch()` method of the class.
>
> A method on a class isn’t quite the same as a standalone function, so
>   you can’t just apply a function decorator to the method – you need to
>   transform it into a method decorator first. The `method_decorator`
>   decorator transforms a function decorator into a method decorator so
>   that it can be used on an instance method. For example:
>
> ```
> from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required 
> from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator 
> from django.views.generic import TemplateView
>
> class ProtectedView(TemplateView):
>     template_name = 'secret.html'
>
>     @method_decorator(login_required)
>     def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
>         return super(ProtectedView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
> ```

Comment: good answer, upvoted. It may be worth mentioning and explaining that if the decoration needs to be applied in several views, the best option is to define and use a Mixin

Comment: But how to add a custom login_url something like `login_url='/account/login/'` in this way?

Comment: I guess `@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/account/login/'))`

Answer (score 2):

Since Django 1.9 you can alternatively use a Mixin for controlling permissions in class based views:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#permission-mixins-for-class-based-views
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin

Comment: links are now dead