# overridding the get_queryset() on rest_framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

i am trying to make a dynamic queryset by overriding the `get-queryset()`
but i get this error:

> queryset is not None, 'base_name argument not specified, and could ' \
>   AssertionError: base_name argument not specified, and could not
>   automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have
>   a `.queryset` attribute.

here is my Views:

```
class TasksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def get_queryset(self):
         return Tasks.objects.filter(assigner=self.request.user)

    serializer_class = TasksSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def perfrom_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(self, assigner=self.request.user.pk)
```

and my urls:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'tasks', views.TasksViewSet)
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

how can I solve this

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace of the error message? Because it is not clear what part of the code is generating the error. Also just define `queryset = Tasks.objects` **and** override `.get_queryset()`. That worked the last time I needed this.

Comment: i defined the `queryset = Tasks.objects` and it worked .. thanks too much

Comment: now i have another problem that when no one is logged in this error raise 
`int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'AnonymousUser'`

Comment: Please make that another question then. And `(assigner=self.request.user)` does not work when `self.request.user` is `AnonymousUser`, since --by default-- the `AnonymousUser` isn't a database entry. [`@login_required`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231682/how-to-use-login-required-in-django-rest-view) might solve your problem most effectively, though..