# Django: djangorestframework-jwt: How to use it for normal DJango views rather than DRF views

Tags: django, jwt

I created an api end point for creating new user using Django views rather than DRF.

```
@csrf_exempt
def user_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_data = json.loads(request.body)
        form = MyUserCreationForm(form_data)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            payload = {
                'id': user.id,
                'username': user.username,
            }

            jwt_token = {'token': jwt.encode(payload, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')}

            response = HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(jwt_token, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder),
                content_type="application/json"
            )

            return response
```

Now if the user is created i get the JSON with jwt token.

I want to create another Django view which will verify user based on jwt token and if authenticated send me the required information.

In normal django view we use @login_required which allows the middleware to check for authentication.

Is there any thing similar for jwt with normal django views.

I know djangorestframework-jwt works with DRF views by adding it to the middleware of DRF settings.

If i add djangorestframework-jwt to the middleware settings of Django views will it work.

Comment: Why can't you use @login_required? it's just a decorator under any **function** that checks if user is authorized.

Comment: just like @login_required how to implement for jwt

Comment: try this, this is cleanest solution.. worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/33232614/5804671