# DRF APIview with authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a class someAPI(APIView). I would like this one to be accessed by only authorised users.

I tried this link [How to use login_required in django rest view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33231682/how-to-use-login-required-in-django-rest-view/33232614)

and

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

but none of them seem work.

My current authentication protocol is logging in with username and password. I guess a reason is because I implement this authentication with basic django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/) but not DRF.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions
from django.http import JsonResponse

class APICostAnalysisController(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    def get(self, request):
        """ Initiate get API for getting cost analysis """
        return JsonResponse(APICostAnalysisImpl().get(), safe=False,json_dumps_params={'indent': 2})
```

Comment: You should add the [**`authentication_classes`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme) attribute too

Comment: I had tried it, but it didn't work. I believe that ```authentication_classes = [authentication.SessionAuthentication, authentication.BasicAuthentication]``` won't work because the login implementation I'm using is not DRF-based, but basic Django based.

Comment: try this one : https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html